# EProblem with Thymeleaf

Tags: java, spring-boot, thymeleaf

Im trying to go simple web application using Spring-Boot, Thymeleaf and Hibernate. Hibernate works well : List sessions is not Empty.

Thymeleaf dont show my view. Im a beginner and cant resolve this problem, please, help.

```
@Controller
public class IndexController {

    @Autowired
    FormSessionRepository formSessionRepository;

    @RequestMapping("/")
    public ModelAndView index() {
        ModelAndView index = new ModelAndView("index");
        List<FormSession> sessions = formSessionRepository.findAll();
        index.addObject("sessions", sessions);
        return index;

    }

}

<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html th="http://thymeleaf.org" xmlns:th="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/orm">
<header><title>Home Page</title></header>
<link href="button.css" rel="stylesheet">
<body>
<div class="wrapper">
    <a href="#" class="button"/>GET RESPONSE</a>
    <a href="#" class="button"/>GET RESPONSE</a>
    <a href="#" class="button"/>GET RESPONSE</a>
</div>
<table>
    <tr th:each="session : ${sessions}">
        <td th:text="${session.getId}">1</td>
    </tr>
</table>

</body>
</html>
```

Error stackTrace:

```
There was an unexpected error (type=Internal Server Error, status=500).
An error happened during template parsing (template: "class path resource [templates/index.html]")
org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateInputException: An error happened during template parsing (template: "class path resource [templates/index.html]")
    at org.thymeleaf.templateparser.markup.AbstractMarkupTemplateParser.parse(AbstractMarkupTemplateParser.java:241)
    at org.thymeleaf.templateparser.markup.AbstractMarkupTemplateParser.parseStandalone(AbstractMarkupTemplateParser.java:100)
    at org.thymeleaf.engine.TemplateManager.parseAndProcess(TemplateManager.java:666)
    at org.thymeleaf.TemplateEngine.process(TemplateEngine.java:1098)
    at org.thymeleaf.TemplateEngine.process(TemplateEngine.java:1072)
    at org.thymeleaf.spring5.view.ThymeleafView.renderFragment(ThymeleafView.java:362)
    at org.thymeleaf.spring5.view.ThymeleafView.render(ThymeleafView.java:189)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1370)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.processDispatchResult(DispatcherServlet.java:1116)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1055)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:942)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1005)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:897)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:634)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have find solution! It was pretty easy. "session" is a reserved word, and when I have changed my code to this it works well.

```
<table>
    <tr th:each="formsession : ${sessions}">
        <td th:text="${formsession.id}">1</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to change Your code in the Controller to:

```
@RequestMapping("/")
public ModelAndView index(Model model) {
    ModelAndView index = new ModelAndView("index");
    List<FormSession> sessions = formSessionRepository.findAll();
    model.addAttribute("sessions", sessions);
    return index;
}
```

and while You are using Thymeleaf, it will probably suffice to use:

```
@RequestMapping("/")
public String index(Model model) {
    List<FormSession> sessions = formSessionRepository.findAll();
    model.addAttribute("sessions", sessions);
    return "index";
}
```

Comment: @Glasch check the changes I made to my answer.

Comment: @Glasch try to replace `session.getId` with `session.Id` or `session.id`

Comment: No changes, the same stackTrace.